# Make [foreach] a synonym of [for-loop]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

[foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreach) is a subset of [for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for-loop), and is not distinct enough to have its own tag, so it should be made its synonym.

As an example, the *for loop* in Python is what would be called *foreach* in some other language, but only strange people would call the Python version a *foreach* loop.

Comment: Of *course* you'd think of those people as strange. You're not one of them.

Comment: There's not only Python out there. PHP, for example, has both `foreach` and `for`, I don't see why they should be treated the same

Comment: @BoltClock There are a lot more people tagging Python Questions [with *for-loop*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+for-loop) than [with *foreach*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+foreach). 1500+ versus 20.

Answer (score 14):

No, I don't think so.  A `foreach` loop is semantically different from a `for-loop.`

A for loop is primarily intended to be used in *bounded contexts,* meaning situations where you know the beginning and end of the loop numerically (traversing arrays, for example).

A `foreach` loop is primarily intended to be used with *lists or other sequences,* where the number of elements does not matter.  It is the loop that would be used when some sort of filter is involved.

While in Python, Bash and Perl a `for` might be the same as a `foreach`, in other languages they are distinct, and are treated differently.

Comment: It's not just Python, but also Bash that uses `for` as a `foreach`. I don't know who else.

Comment: @Tshepang: Doesn't really matter.  The fact that there are languages that don't, is proof enough that they're two different things and deserve their own tags (if *either* of them deserve a tag, at least...which i'm not sure about).

Comment: @Tshepang: The site isn't Python Overflow, Bash Overflow or Python Bash Overflow. The whole site doesn't revolve around your language of choice, it is a repository of useful solutions to common programming problems for programmers everywhere. That includes every other programming language there is. Search conventions should not be limited to the conventions of one language.